# Cannot create orders more than 50,000 INR - Razorpay

Tags: razorpay

I'm using the test mode of Razorpay and creating an order with Orders API. It says in the [FAQ](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-pages/faqs/) (Point 13) that maximum payment amount allowed per transaction on a Payment Page is INR 500,000/-. But as soon as I create order more than 50,000 (amount field in Orders API is set to 50,00,000 because you have to send paise amount, not the rupee amount), API respond back with an error 400 :

```
    "error": {
        "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "description": "Amount exceeds maximum amount allowed.",
        "source": null,
        "step": null,
        "reason": null,
        "metadata": {},
        "field": "amount"
    }
}
```

I tried doing 5,00,00,000 (paise equivalent of 5Lacs) in test as well as live API but the same error comes up. Why does this happen?